# How to do Boolean filtering with two strings as conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I'm trying to use boolean filtering to create a new dataframe in pandas where the entries in the column 'job_id' match the values in the series 'x'.

This is what i've tried although the | operator doesnt work on strings, so i'm unsure what to do.

```
x = jobs[jobs['job_title'].isin(['Sales Representative', 'Sales Manager'])]['job_id']
employees['job_id'][(x[7]) | (x[8])]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `employees[employees['job_id'].isin(x.tolist())]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer without a reproducible example to work with, but I think the problem is just to change to:

```
employees['job_id'][ (employees['job_id'] == x[7]) | (employees['job_id'] == x[8]) ]
```

Your code doesn't contain any boolean test. This works for me at least using the example below which shows that | can definitely be used with strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
df['num_specimen_seen'][(df['letter'] == 'a') | (df['letter'] == 'b')]
df['letter'][(df['letter'] == 'a') | (df['letter'] == 'b')]
```